# Inserting into multiple tables with a CTE Not working for me

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I saw some answers here for some common CTE use cases to insert into multiple tables, when trying to do the same steps, I end up with an error saying

> Missing From-clause entry for table "first_insert" position 824.

My CTE expression is as follows,

```
with first_insert as (
    insert into listing (title, slug, price, min_quantity, serves, currency_name, currency_symbol, img_url, description,
                         location, g_map_address, vendor_id)
        values ('hello', 'hello-1234', 1, 12, 10, 'eur', '€','url.jpg',
                'description', point(24.5498, 16.26), 'gmap', 1)
        RETURNING id
),
     second_insert as (
         insert into category (name, suggested_name, link, rel_link, listing_id)
             select 'name', 'name', 'link', 'rel_link', id
             from first_insert
     ),
     third_insert as (
         insert into allergen (name, suggested_name, link, rel_link, listing_id)
             select 'name', 'name', 'link', 'rel_link', id
             from first_insert
     )
insert into image(listing_id, img_url) select first_insert.id, 'imgUrl';
```

1 - How can I get this working, as inserts don't require from so not sure where to even start with that

2 - Is this the best way in terms of performance to execute these types of inserts?

3 - Is this classified as a safe inserts such that if any one of the inserts fails with the already executed inserts be rolled back?

4 - Is there a better overall way of doing such an insert in terms of performance and safety?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 - How can I get this working, as inserts don't require from so not sure where to even start with that

It's complaining about the "final" query, you don't have a FROM clause in it. It should be this:

```sql
...
insert into image(listing_id, img_url) select id, 'imgUrl' from first_insert;
```

> 2 - Is this the best way in terms of performance to execute these types of inserts?

Performance should be similar to doing BEGIN + the 4 inserts as separate queries + COMMIT. It's maybe slightly faster because you're saving network roundtrips between the application and the database, but I don't think this will make a difference in a normal application. I'd use whatever way feels more readable/maintainable to you.

> 3 - Is this classified as a safe inserts such that if any one of the inserts fails with the already executed inserts be rolled back?

Yes, queries in Postgres are automatically executed within their own transaction (if you haven't already started a transaction of your own). This means either all or none of its effects get committed to disk, but never part.

> 4 - Is there a better overall way of doing such an insert in terms of performance and safety?

I don't think there's a better way for performance. For safety, this is equally safe as running the 4 inserts separately in a transaction.

For maintainability/readability, I'd say it's somewhate better to do the 4 inserts separately in a transaction. It's less esoteric and more flexible. What if in the future you want to insert into `allergen` only if a certain condition is met? If you're doing the queries separately it's super easy to add an `if`, but if you're doing them all in one big query it becomes more complicated.

Comment: Thats done the job, was missing the form in the last query, thanks for the advice, I've decided to go with the similar multi-insert way for now, if i ever require the extra performance ill look more into the CTE expressions.